# How to give a client a JWT while a redirection?

Tags: python, django, django-views, jwt

I'm working on a web app in django, and I'm facing a problem in implementing a JWT authentication. I have a django application which is responsible for user management and therefore authentication. So when I authenticate a user in my view, I have to redirect him to the home page which is in another django application. But here is the problem, when I authenticate a user, I create a JWT and pass it to the response so that the client of the user can store it, but it seems that when redirecting, the client cannot store the JWT.
Here is the view that authenticate the users :

```
def loginUser(request: HttpRequest):
    """
    Request :
        URL : /user/loginUser/
        Method : POST
        Content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        Required informations :
            -username
            -password
    
    Response :
        Status : 302
        Redirect url : /home
    """

    if request.method != "POST":
        return JsonResponse(
            data={"error":"Bad request method."},
            hearders={"Allow":"POST"},
            status=405,
        )
    
    try:
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
    except KeyError:
        return redirect("/user/loginPage/?error=Missing informations")

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user != None:
        exp = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=3)
        exp = int(exp.timestamp())

        payload = {
            "user_id":user.id,
            "username":user.username,
            "exp":exp
        }
        token = jwt.encode(payload=payload, key=JWT_KEY)

        response = HttpResponse(status=302)
        response["Location"] = "/home"
        response["Authorization"] = "Bearer "+str(token)

        return response

    else:
        return redirect("/user/loginPage/?error=Bad identifiers")
```

The obvious solution would be to simply not redirect, but that's the last thing I want to do as I want to remain consistent in my code. Another solution would be to not use JWT, but again, that's not what I want. I thought of putting the token as a url parameter, but I understand that this is not ideal in terms of security. I don't have any other idea, which is why I refer to you. Thank you for taking the time to listen to me.

Comment: You could redirect the user using JavaScript. First, gather the token and let the user store it locally, then redirect to the given URL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alexander Schillemans for your response. I've come up with a simple solution, if anyone run into this problem, just encrypt the JWT and then pass it as a url parameter. That way, there are no more security concerns.